# Putty SSH connection timed out but OVH KVM ok

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, kvm-virtualization

I dont know why today SSH give me an error but i can ping server and connect to SSH via OVH panel with KVM

I reboot my server, load new config in putty, change try alive option to 200, change user but always i have connection timed out

The problem is from putty, my server or my ip ? I dont have iptables or fail2ban and password is good
Thanks

Comment: Do you use a AV that do network filtering?

Comment: No i disable all firewall or av, change ssh port and not work, but after i reboot my server in rescue mode its work... what is solution without rescue mode pls ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting from a different IP (You may be blocked for some reason)?

Comment: Yes i think is from ip because today all work... but i dont have iptables or fail2ban its possible the problem is from ovh ? or fingerprint conflict ?